# Start gradient effect after the 80% of the sceen height

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient

What i want to achieve is to make a gradient drawable that the gradient effect starts at the bottom of the view, lets say after the 80% of the view's height. 
So i want most of the view (80%) covered with startColor.

I tried:

```
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#70C272"
    android:endColor="#F19941"
    android:centerX="80%"
    android:centerY="100%"
    />
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:

Edit:

Using ShapeDrawable:

```
        ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf=new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
            @Override
            public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
                final float DY = 60;
                final float heightFraction = height * 0.8f;
                return new LinearGradient(0,heightFraction-DY,0,heightFraction+DY,
                   //      new int[] {Color.parseColor("#E44342"), Color.parseColor("#F19941")},
                        new int[] {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN},
                         new float[]{0.5f, 1},
                         Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
            }
        };
        ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
        sd.setShaderFactory(sf);
```

Comment: you can use 2 views and their backgrounds in a LinearLayout - 1st view can take 80% weight, and have a solid color background, the 2nd - 20% weight and gradient background.

Comment: @Manos to which view that you are applying it?

Comment: @Charuක This is rather complicated. I try to apply it to a LineDataSet (setFillDrawable(Drawable d); of mpandroidchart. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/DataSet-classes-in-detail

Comment: @Manos  do you have only that data set in your screen i can suggest a workaround

Comment: @Charuක Check Edit. Each different color is made of two datasets

Comment: @Manos just asking to clear is that your 20% from bottom ? and what are those four layers ;)

Comment: @Charuක Those four layers are datasets with fill in between them. Each color has two datasets. One for the bottom border and one for the top border with fill color between them. I want to replace this fill with a gradient (drawable) to achieve what the second image shows.

Comment: @Manos  well ill give you an answer for applying gradient it might help

Comment: use a `ShapeDrawable` and setup its `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory`

Comment: and remember: simple `new ShapeDrawable()` will not work - you need a `Shape` based ctor for it to work (or call `setShape`)

Comment: @pskink A short example would be highly appreciated!

Comment: `ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape();` then call `setShaderFactory` where you return your `LinearGradient`

Comment: it takes `float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1` you are passing `0, width, 0, height`, also `positions` array should to be in ascending order

Comment: @pskink sample answer will be helpful to him i guess

Comment: @pskink what's wrong with the coordinates? for the positions array i was just experimenting

Comment: you are passing `width` as `y0`, is it really what you want (width is in x axis...)? and try `positions` like `{0, 0.33f, 1}`

Comment: I want the gradient to be vertical and I want the gradient effect to start after the 80% of the height.

Comment: then use `0, 0, 0, height` and `{0.8f, 0.9f, 1}`

Comment: @pskink Check edit. With this code all the drawable has the first color of the array. No gradient effect. By the way I need two colors.

Comment: here https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAHSl.png there are four colors, not two (two of them are the same)

Comment: Each color at the picture will take a different drawable. I am trying now to do it only for the top one and when i manage to make it how I want it i will do it for the rest as well. For example, the first one will take as start color the red and as end color the yellow.

Comment: `float y = height * 0.8f;
                final float DY = 20;
                return new LinearGradient(0, y-DY, 0, y+DY, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);` adjust DY to be screen resolution independent by using some dimen.xml resources

Comment: @pskink https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15854314/Screenshot_20170214-164550.png Getting somewhere but still needs something. The screenshot is with the code used at the edit. With TileMode.CLAMP i get only blue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xBctSZKN what do you see if you run that testing code at the bottom?

Comment: The height i get from resize(...) is for the whole view. Although i need the height for only the top color.

Comment: do you see red color at the top, yellow at the bottom and smooth gradient change around 80% of the height? isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: I found a way to do it, I will post it tomorrow!

Comment: so most likely you should not use 0.8f but some smaller value...

Answer (score 1):

Well If you want to apply gradient for the bottom 20% of your View this is my approach,

- I have a `FrameLayout` as the XML root
- `LinearLayout`  for gradient with background of gradient.XML

**my xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     // whatever your views 


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_view_gradient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_draw"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

drawable resource **gradient_draw.xml** (you can use your own colors)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#70C27200"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:centerX="80%"
        android:centerY="100%"
        />

    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Now I set this to bottom 20%

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private int height,width;
    private LinearLayout linearLayoutGradient ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        linearLayoutGradient = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view_gradient);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLparams= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (height*20)/100);
        frameLparams.topMargin = (height*80)/100;
        linearLayoutGradient.setLayoutParams(frameLparams);

    }

}
```

Comment: This will not work since i can only work with Drawables

Comment: @Manos you dont have a layout ?

Comment: The layout is build in the library (mpandroidchart)

Comment: @Manos what if you dynamically create that linear layout and add its background and set it ?

Comment: @Manos  from your question its hard to get that part you should mention that otherwise answers will waste :[

Comment: I can only pass drawables to the method. (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/a3c1fe6bbf7d48b79b42b3a447f946af850d86f0/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineRadarDataSet.java#L77)

Comment: Excuse me for that... Do you have any workaround suggestion for my needs? :)

Comment: @Manos depends on that library mm you better add that as well in your question ill have a look into that lib

Comment: @Manos if you need a `Drawable` then use that `ShapeDrawable`

Comment: @pskink I am trying and i managed to do it, but still i cant make the gradient effect only in between the change of the colors as show at the last image in the question

Comment: @Manos how are you creating a `LinearGradient`?